# Single application.properties for main and test module

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

I do have a lot of shared properties across my `main` and `test` module. It seems that when running the modules the only properties that are picked up are located inside the `<module>/resources/application.properties` the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) does not mention the `resource` folder, while there is nothing in my grade configuration.

Have anyone had any success with sharing properties across modules without having to:
* use `spring.config.location`
* copy the configuration as part of the gradle script
* have a custom configuration in IntelliJ to use the correct config file

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `application-test.properties` file in `src/test/resources` and make all your tests use the `test` profile, which will overlay the default `application.properties` file values.

This allows you to use your defaults but change only the props you need different for testing.

This also allows you to create different test profiles for different types of tests - by simply creating a new file and specifying a different profile.

See Also: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html